# urllib2 doesn't download file with wild characters

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a python script which takes the input argument as the path of a directory and file and downloads the file. My code looks as below

```
def fetch_file(file_url, downloadPath):
    link = urllib2.urlopen(file_url)
    Opening the destination path and writing the contents
```

The problem is in the source I have many files with a common prefix as below:
file_1.txt

file_2.txt

file_3.txt
......
test.py etc

I want to pass the arguments as a single string say file*.txt. But the urllib2 is not working with that. Can I use a pattern based search and download the files which start with file and end with txt? Any suggestions?

Comment: No you can't. Your python code does not know the urls to the files on the (remote) server. you need to add all filenames in a list, then loop over it to construct the proper urls and then fetch the files.

Comment: However, depending on the access rules on the server, you could possibly use urlopen() to read the contents of the directory. If this succeeds, you could then iterate over the contents, manually searching for files that match your pattern.

Comment: Windows File Explorer can open FTP directly. If you can host on an FTP server, you might be able to simply iterate over the folder with the `open` function

Comment: Of course, beware of speed issues